# Ubuntu pl2303 usbserial overflow?

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port, usb

I am connecting a currentcost electricity monitor to my ubuntu server and am using the method to connect as described here ...

[putting your watts on the web](http://martgadget.blogspot.com/2009/09/putting-your-watts-on-web.html)

```
#!/bin/sh

/opt/bin/head /dev/ttyUSB0 -n1 | /bin/grep '<ch1><watts>' | /bin/sed -e s/\<ch1\>\<watts\>/\ / | /opt/bin/cut -d' ' -f2 | /opt/bin/cut -c1-5
```

Now, I am also having the same problem as described here ... [putting your watts on the web, part 2](http://martgadget.blogspot.com/2010/01/putting-your-watts-on-web-part-2-for.html)

The data hangs where the `head` command pulls the data. It works for a while then randomly stops.

Firstly, I would like to know whether I can virtually unplug and reinsert the USB device `/dev/ttyUSB0`, so I can at least fix the problem remotely when it happens.

Secondly, what would be the best method of investigating the cause? Alternatively, should I be looking at writing a C program to do this instead? I know very little C, so this would be a challenge.

Comment: are you 100% sure that the `head` command is even getting output from the device when it hangs?  You may need to just run that `head` command alone (with no arguments) for a while to ensure you know the output that happens under all circumstances

Comment: PL2303 on Ubuntu 16.04 Default Permission for /dev/ttyUSB0:  crw-rw----   I had to run chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0 so that my serial terminal (Cutecom) could access the device.  If the device is automatically broadcasting data, connecting it to Cutecom is a good smoke test.

Answer (score 0):

For a C snippet that (purportedly) equals an unplug/replug cycle, see [here](http://www.roman10.net/?p=312).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a file permissions issue?  It was for me: PL2303 on Ubuntu 16.04 Default Permission for /dev/ttyUSB0: crw-rw---- I had to run chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0 so that my serial terminal (Cutecom) could access the device. If the device is automatically broadcasting data,    connecting it to Cutecom is a good smoke test.